# what is the structure of table for request and accept?

Tags: database, laravel

I have two table cvs and users.
users can enter the cv data and save in database.
one user cannot access the cv data entered by another user.
To access the cv of another user one has to request first and then can access if it is approved.
For this how can i setup my table in database?
like friend request and accept

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Your codes and errors.

Comment: @Sachith Haven't tried. I am a beginner so confused how to start this.

Comment: Please try something first, even though its completely wrong. then post your question. Its the best way to get help from SO

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:
[image]

This way the creator of the cv (or owner) is set as user_id at the cvs giving the creator access to its own cv.

If you want to give someone access to your cv, add a new record to the curriculum_vitea_user table and set the accepted to false.

The user that created this cv can accept this request and the accepted will be set to true.

If the accepted is true then the user can view the cv of the other person.

I hope that this will help you on your way.